# Is there any knapsack-based cryptosystem that hasn't been broken?

Tags: cryptography, knapsack-problems

I took part in the development of a [knapsack-based asymmetric cryptosystem](http://srvbblog.wordpress.com/), and am currently planing to launch a campaign to promote it.

Before we actually do, it occurred to me to research...

**what were all the attempts of knapsack-based cryptosystem, ever devised and which of them have been broken?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems quite broad request to enumerate all attempts. Have you found any of them?

Comment: What research have you done? How have you searched? Have you done a [literature search](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351)?  Expecting us to do that for you doesn't seem reasonable; this isn't a place where you can outsource work to others.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research, and show us in the question what approach you took, what you found so far, and articulate a more specific question.  (And it'll benefit you to familiarize yourself with the literature.) Also, asking for a list of *all* knapsack-based cryptosystems seems too broad to me; see our [help/dont-ask].